# Numpy: Maximal Value is NaN

Tags: python, numpy

My question about Python is really trivial: What do I have to modify that the function `max()` returns a real value for any compiler?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 0, 1, np.nan])
# The maximal value is 1. It is not nan!
a.max()
```

There is the possibility to use the following code but it looks ugly to me:

```
a[np.logical_not(np.isnan(a))].max()
```

Comment: Use [`np.nanmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html).

Comment: Seems really what I was looking for! Thank you. BTW: Can I use it also in the dot-notation `a.nanmax()`?

Comment: Nope, it won't work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was answered by @Divakar using [`np.nanmax(a)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html) will solve your question.